# Reducing AppStore App Size: Remove System.Xml?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am looking for ways to reduce my App Store app size. I am using Xamarin Forms with PCL. One of the things I see in the `AppStore` build output (in `../obj/iPhone/AppStore/mtouch-cache`) of my app is `System.Xml.dll.armv7.o` and `System.Xml.dll.arm64.o` totaling ~12mb. After `mscorlib`, this is the largest component to my build output. See screenshot:

[image: ls -laS *.o]

My application does not do anything with Xml, so I want to remove this dependency reference if possible. I tried removing all references to `System.Xml` from my projects, but that does not seem to change anything. Can I remove this some way? Why is `System.Xml` in my build output?

My project source can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/bitwarden/mobile

Answer (score 2):

> Why is System.Xml in my build output?

The managed linker (unless disabled) will remove any non-required assembly from your application. If you still see `System.Xml.dll` it either means:

- the linker is set to **Don't link**, the default for devices is **Link SDK**;
- some other assemblies (e.g. 3rd parties) are using `System.Xml` and it cannot be removed from your application.

> Can I remove this some way?

Yes. You can use the **Assembly Browser** do see references from 3rd parties assemblies. Once they are identified you can:

- Remove the dependencies from your project and replace it with something that does not depend on `System.Xml`. That can be quite easy or very hard; or
- Set the linker to **Link all** to see if it can eliminate the XML references from the 3rd party. Be aware that you might need to add `[Preserve]` on your (and other 3rd party code) to cover cases like reflection (which the linker can't detect using static analysis);

Beside the documentation on Xamarin's web site you can watch the video of my **[Advanced iOS Build mechanics](http://xamarin.com/evolve/2013#session-37jlfjcqmn)** talk I gave at [Evolve 2013](http://xamarin.com/evolve/2013). It covers to pros and cons of most settings.

Comment: I do have the full linker turned on. From what I can tell the only packages that I have that utilize `System.Xml` are Json.NET and Xamarin.Forms. I am not using the features of Json.NET that invoke System.Xml. Is `System.Xml` required because of Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Also, I seen to be having issues getting anything useful out of the Assembly Browser. I do not see any of my third party libraries listed in it. Is there any information out there on how to use this feature? A quick google didn't turn up much.